# Something calls a method when the app is in the background

Tags: swift, timer, background, nsrunloop

I am using a timer to check certain conditions every minute. Timer code:

```
func startTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer?.tolerance = 0.2
        timer = Timer.init(fire: Day.dateWithNextMinute(), interval: 5, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.checkToPass()
        }
        RunLoop.current.add(timer!, forMode: .default)
    }
```

Everything works correctly.

But there were problems: for some users, the application began to crash when app is in the background, due to an unhandled value in the checkToPass() method (identified by the logs).
I can't figure out how this method can be called when the application is in the background. Is it possible that **RunLoop** has a side effect and somehow the body of the timer can be called (in the background)? Or maybe it's the **timer**?

No specific crash time was found. The app was just in the background.
  Thanks for any ideas

Comment: your app can't run timer on the background, the background mode is available for few cases.https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started.

Comment: @cristian_064 thanks for the answer. I understand that the timer shouldn't and doesn't run in the background. But users experienced a crash in a method that is called only in the body of the timer. The crash occurs generally at a random point in time, not after the application is minimized.
The crash issue has already been fixed. But the scenario remains unclear, which is why I started this ticket.
it feels like the app at some point executes a method from the timer and crashes, but why does it execute it..